# Pergunta sobre XGH/GHP (Go Horse), benéfico ou prejudicial a comunidade?

Tags: debate, perguntas, pergunta-específica

Não estou aqui para perguntar se a pergunta é dentro do escopo ou fora (off-topic) ou se ela deveria ser fechada por qualquer motivo que seja, o que estou querendo discutir é a qualidade e ao mesmo tempo a imagem do site lá fora.

O GoHorse, como eu [expliquei](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/164139/3635) é uma crítica e *forma de sátira* sobre o desenvolvimento de software e empresas, ou seja é algo que está ligado a informática e se tornou um termo, ou seja é algo que "existe".

Mas a pergunta aqui não é se existe ou não, se é on-topic ou não. As questões são:

- Ela é útil à comunidade e futuros visitantes?
- Ela trará benefícios?
- Se acaso ela for prejudicial, seria o caso de removê-la (isso porque fechar ainda seria pública e remover ela seria "privada")?

Comment: Não, não e não. Apesar de não achar util e nem acreditar que ela traga algum beneficio pro site, também não acho que deva ser removida por completa.

Comment: Sobre o assunto, dei uma olhada lá, acho que talvez seria mais adequado como wiki. Não tenho certeza. Quem é mais antigo e entende mais do site, talvez possa entender melhor o que fazer.

Comment: Para mim falta razoabilidade em algumas decisões tomadas aqui. A pergunta realmente não acrescenta valor nenhum com respeito a soluções na programação. Em contra partida, os tópicos de explicação de como funciona a metodologia apresentam as consequências de usá-la, mas de forma satírica. Mesmo que alguns achem que a pergunta não seja útil, não significa que ela vai manchar o site, atrapalhar o crescimento da comunidade ou fazer com que os usuários novos percam de vista o objetivo da comunidade. A cultura daqui é muito engessada. Claro que não deve haver exageros.

Comment: Pode ser que essa pergunta abra brechas ou precedentes para outros fazer o mesmo. Mas aí é que entra a moderação em julgar se realmente a pergunta foi feita com a motivação de fazer piada. Querer ganhar votos acredito que não entre nessa questão. Muitos aqui querem ganhar votos por fazer boas perguntas ou dar boas respostas. O que pode ser uma boa resposta ou pergunta pra mim pode não ser pra outro usuário. É relativo. E existe aqueles que não sabem votar. Na minha opinião, respostas enormes me cansam, quando eu quero apenas ver um exemplo e uma simples explicação.

Comment: @Gumball Concordo com quase tudo do seu primeiro comentário, menos com *cultura engessada*, eu acho a nossa cultura muito bem definida, na verdade eu acho ela melhor que a do SOen, aqui ao menos a maioria segue um mesmo pensamento pois definimos bem o que queremos e o que precisamos, tem uma ou outra situação contraditora, que é causada por usuários que não entendem a comunidade e por quem não aceita como é ou a situação aqui da pergunta no META, aonde levamos para um debate, mas são casos raros. Já no SOen existe muita divergência. Resumindo, o SOpt não me parece ter uma cultura engessada.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Debates raros e pouca divergência são basicamente a definição de "cultura engessada". Não defendo que nossa cultura aqui seja muito engessada no momento, mas ela tem tudo pra se tornar assim, se nosso objetivo for ter pouco debate, ao invés de recebê-los de mente aberta, e dispostos a mudar nossas próprias regras para evoluirmos.

Comment: @Gabe eu vejo bastante debate, não acho que ser convicto de uma opinião ou regra seja não aceitar debates. Afinal um individuo que muda facilmente de opinião é porque não acredita de verdade no que defende ou porque o que defendia estava muito errado, se o pessoal experiente "bate o pé" não foi algo definido da noite para o dia, não consigo ver isto como "engessado". Eu vejo muito debate entre o pessoal experiente, só notar o pessoal no chat, eu mesmo não concordo inteiramente com quase ninguem, veja meus dialogos com Bacco e Bigown. Eu entendo o que disse, só que não acho que seja isso.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Eu não disse que nossa comunidade não tem debates. Ou que está engessada. Disse que ter pouco debate **não pode ser nosso objetivo**. Assim como manter o debate apenas entre os mais experientes. A maneira como você descreveu nossa comunidade no primeiro comentário (temos uma cultura "muito bem definida", onde situações contraditórias são "causadas por usuários que não entendem a comunidade" ou quem "não aceita como ela é", com "casos raros de debate") não condiz com o ideal que deveriamos almejar.

Comment: @Gabe eu também não disse isso, eu disse que tem bastante debate e você disse que tem tudo para se tornar engessado, eu falei que do meu ponto de vista há bastante debate sim, não disse que esta ou não engessado. Eu também não disse que mantemos o debate entre os mais experientes, eu citei aquilo como exemplo, o que eu queria que entendesse é que há debate em todos lugares mesmo até entre o pessoal experiente que segue um pensamento parecido. Todos que sejam interessados que venham participar do META e chat, sempre convidamos novatos a entrarem.

Answer (score 20):

> Ela é útil à comunidade e futuros visitantes?
>   Ela trará benefícios?

Sim, pois pessoas podem esbarrar no termo XGH em diversos locais e ficar em dúvida. Este é um termo referente a tecnologias e à programação, então, nada mais natural do que ter uma pergunta sobre terminologia explicando o que é XGH.

> Se acaso ela for prejudicial, seria o caso de removê-la (isso porque fechar ainda seria pública e remover ela seria "privada")?

Não vejo como isso pode ser prejudicial. O termo XGH e a sua definição foram feitos de forma satírica, mas ela tem um propósito bem sério: Conscientizar e demonstrar o que é que ocorre quando há falta na adoção de um processo de desenvolvimento de software maduro e também denunciar que é isso o que mais ocorre na prática no mundo real.

Comment: Concordo em tudo, principalmente que tem um propósito "bem sério"

Comment: Quem sentou o dedo aí no down, gostaria de dissertar acerca de seu ponto de vista?

Comment: É o minimo, afinal aqui é um debate :/

Comment: Dá sim, não dá pra esperar um pouco? O tempo pra votar é 1 segundo ou menos. Escrever uma resposta leva um pouco mais de tempo...

Comment: @jbueno Ok. Estou no aguardo. Desculpe a pressa.

Comment: Já termino a resposta, vou ter que correr pra apagar fogo aqui. Vou manter meu voto por discordar do que foi dito (acho que no meta os votos são um pouco diferente). Aliás, é só meu ponto de vista, até depois. Amplexos.

Comment: @jbueno Tranquilo, afinal a ideia do debate é essa mesmo e é assim que a comunidade cresce e (re)definimos novas políticas para ela.

Comment: @VictorStafusa vou focar na resposta do bigown, ela diz quase tudo o que eu penso. Peço desculpas pela demora e também pela falta de cortesia no primeiro comentário *=)*

Comment: Concordo. Ainda vou mais longe (porque é meu estilo): Mesmo que não houvesse um "benefício indireto" de conscientização - como o Victor Stafusa apresentou - ainda acreditaria que a pergunta tem lugar por dizer respeito à *cultura* de programação. Nem tudo que envolve programação, e que forma programadores, é estritamente técnico. Algumas coisas são meramente culturais, XGH ou hacker koans por exemplo. Ambos podem ter respostas claras e bem definidas sobre seus sentidos, sem entrar em nenhum detalhe técnico. E ambos constribuem para a formação de uma *cultura de programadores* no site.

Answer (score 7):

Ficou claro que além de mim, não muito mais que duas pessoas concordam que esse tipo de conteúdo não é bom para o site.

Eu não acho que realmente ele ensine algo, é só uma piada, não tem informação relevante aí. Eu poderia tentar mostrar ponto por ponto do assunto que não está ensinando nada útil, mas sei que não vai mudar a opinião de ninguém.

Já falei algumas vezes que eu posso fazer uma pergunta melhor do que essa que está sendo discutida aqui sobre *cartoon*. Um assunto que é banido. Faça a pergunta de um jeito que fica parecendo mais que essa pergunta sendo discutida que é para gerar algum conhecimento relevante e útil. Tenho a desculpa perfeita para que se fale de uma piada e da um ar de coisa séria. E de verdade, terá alguma informação útil, ensinará alguém fazer alguma coisa melhor. Mas no fundo será só para fazer graça e ganhar reputação fácil porque esse tipo de coisa chama a atenção, as pessoas votam porque acharam divertido. Se fosse pela utilidade tem um monte de coisa bem mais útil com dois ou três votos.

Acho ruim ter esse vínculo, mas por mim não faço questão.

Aceitar esse tipo de pergunta abre precedente. Vivam com ele.

Comment: O importante é ter o contra e explicado, isso porque na maioria dos casos as pessoas não tem opiniões formadas inteiramente e acabam por ir pelo que lhes parece "melhor", então hoje eu (Guilherme) acredito em uma coisa, você me mostra algo que contraria o que penso, eu tendo bom senso vou ler e refletir, resumindo hoje a maioria parece acreditar que ela é até útil, mas as vezes um opinião bem formada apontando os problemas ou situações pode mudar a opinião de muitas pessoas. Então por este motivo achei uma otima resposta. (Claro que a minha opinião pessoal eu vou (re)formular ainda)

Comment: Concordo. Isso vai abrir precedentes, usuários mais novos(ou com bem menos reputação) podem fazer uma pergunta equivalente e, diferente desta, vão ser massacrados com uma chuva de negativos e fechamento relâmpago, se bobear.

Comment: @diegofm não acho sei se é bem este o problema, eu acho que talvez o problema citado pelo bigown refere-se a qualidade/utilidade do(s) conteúdo(s)

Comment: Ganhar reputação fácil enquanto trola o site... Aconteceu várias vezes no SOen. Por exemplo: [Cycles in family tree software](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6163683/664577) (veja que a única participação do "autor" no site foi essa pergunta :D). Por outro lado, pergunta engraçadinhas tem um potencial marketeiro (o pessoal compartilha em redes sociais, etc). É um balanço entre seriedade e alcance. Fica a critério da comunidade.

Comment: Se o pessoal acha que faz falta esta pergunta especifica, pode ser fechada e bloqueada como não construtiva. Como acontece em alguns casos no EN. Eu sinceramente acho que deve estar fechada, mas entendo que possa existir.

Comment: O que a comunidade decidir pra mim tá decidido. Se for bloqueada como não construtiva, vai mostrar que ela tem um problema, daí quem ler não vai fazer a pergunta. Agora, a questão do votos é uma coisa complicada, porque tem coisas ruins que recebem muitos votos, tem coisas boas que recebem poucos votos (ou nem recebem).

Comment: Li a sua resposta e a do jbueno, e não me convenci. Não gosto de dar -1 para vocês dois (mesmo que no meta), mas voto pela ideia e pelo conteúdo, e não pela pessoa. Em especial, você afirma que "*não muito mais que duas pessoas concordam que esse tipo de conteúdo*", o que tendo em vista os números de upvotes/downvotes na pergunta e aqui no meta é uma afirmativa claramente falsa.

Comment: Além disso, o fato de a pergunta ser sobre algo que foi criado de forma satírica não a torna off-topic, vez que continua sendo algo referente ao processo de desenvolvimento de software, que está no escopo do site. Também não é uma pergunta ampla demais, vaga, opinativa, subjetiva, escrita em uma língua que não seja o português, algo não-reproduzível ou erro de digitação, duplicata ou qualquer coisa que se encaixe em algum critério de fechamento existente. E embora verse sobre algo que foi definido de forma satírica, trata-se de uma pergunta séria afinal de contas, sobre a terminologia.

Comment: @VictorStafusa Bom, não esperava de você pegar um trecho da frase para descontextualizar e inverter o que eu disse, vou considerar que foi apenas um deslize e não má fé, mas sua afirmação ali é claramente falsa. O segundo comentário está falando de algo que eu não disse também. Eu só postei porque não fujo do debate, a decisão já está tomada, você tem a sua opinião, eu tenho a minha.

Comment: @bigown Tá, foi burrada minha, li com pressa e não vi o "não" na frase. Desculpe.

Answer (score 7):

> Ela é útil à comunidade e futuros visitantes?

Não, não é. E eu acho difícil que, de alguma forma, este conteúdo (pelo menos da forma que se apresenta hoje) possa ser útil pro site. Ele não instrui a nada, não ensina nada, não resolve nenhum problema, não fala sobre técnicas, enfim, nada relevante.

> Ela trará benefícios?

Como (muito bem) citado pelo colega [@Anthony Accioly](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5447/pergunta-sobre-xgh-ghp-go-horse-ben%C3%A9fico-ou-prejudicial-a-comunidade#comment20512_5453) essa é uma pergunta que serve pra "ganhar reputação enquanto trolla o site".

Tem os dois lados da moeda, as pessoas gostam de ver coisas divertidas. Isso é notável pela quantidade de votos na publicação, eu já vi publicações muito melhores com conteúdos relevantes aqui no site que não chegam a 10 votos, isso mostra que o pessoal aqui quer votar naquilo que acha engraçado/divertido e não em conteúdo que realmente tenta ensinar/instruir algo. A consequência (boa) disso é que possivelmente haverá divulgação desse conteúdo em meios externos (Facebook, Twitter, etc.) - mesmo que isso não seja um comportamento normal dos usuários daqui. A consequência ruim é que isso tira um pouco de seriedade do site, pelo menos eu vejo muito dessa forma. Digo, o termo é uma piada, todo mundo sabe disso e, mesmo quem nunca ouviu falar, 1 minuto de Google já mostra isso.

> Se acaso ela for prejudicial, seria o caso de removê-la (isso porque fechar ainda seria pública e remover ela seria "privada")?

Deixo aberto pra discussão, nesse caso, nem sei o que deveria ser feito. Eu nem faço questão de nada também, eu já dei meu voto pra fechar e poucas pessoas concordaram com ele. A minha opinião tá lá no meu voto e nessa resposta (fora o que conversei com o AP no chat).

---

Aliás, tem algumas coisas que me preocupam que eu devo citar:

- Como já dito pelo [@bigown](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5453/18246), esse tipo de pergunta abre precedentes pra outras desse tipo. Nesse caminho, logo a página de publicações mais votadas vai estar cheia de publicações desse tipo.
- Todo mundo aqui sabe que temos problemas com votos. Nossa comunidade não sabe votar direito. Eu tenho certeza que se essa pergunta tivesse sido feita por alguém com reputação < 10k, ela não só estaria fechada, como teria um saldo de -20.

Comment: Só questiono essa ideia que vai ter divulgação. Até pode ter ter, mas é pouca, em geral tem um lugar mais canônico sobre o assunto para divulgar a piada. Mesmo que tenha, é um benefício mínimo para o preço que se paga. Por outro lado eu também acho que já pagamos boa parte do preço por várias coisas.

Comment: Não tenho certeza da parte do ~10k... tem lugares que isto é valido e tem lugares que não, neste caso eu não acho que teria sido este o motivo. Já rolava a um bom tempo algumas conversas sobre XGH no chat, quem participa lá e viu a pergunta votou porque estava habituado ao assunto, mesmo que usado para tons humorísticos.

Comment: Já escrevi alguns comentários na resposta do bigown. Mas acrescento aqui que o foco não é se isso é algo engraçado/divertido ou não - esse ponto é irrelevante. A pergunta é séria afinal de contas, está questionando o significado de um termo que é encontrado de vez em quando por desenvolvedores de software e que se relaciona diretamente com o desenvolvimento de software - por causa disso é válido. Se esse termo trata-se de algo satírico e jocoso, não é esse o ponto.